# Becoming a veteran in Chivalry: Medieval Warfare

Tags: achievements, chivalry-medieval-warfare

I noticed that there is an achievement for each class for becoming a veteran of the class, but I can't find anywhere on the net how you would do this.

Anybody know how to become a veteran?

Answer (score 7):

You become a Veteran in a specific class by unlocking every single primary weapon for that class. This unlocks an achievement and the Veteran helmet for that class, equipable from the main menu.

Comment: was it every weapon for that class, or only the primary slot weapons?

Comment: Primary. I got veteran Vanguard without the secondaries. Will edit this answer

Comment: do we unlock anything for the secondary? I don't think so...

Comment: I have every single weapon for the archer but im still not veteran

Comment: @MaxenceFulconis that's just a bug in one of the updates. The newest update as of now should solve that problem (it did for me)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you just unlock all the primary weapons for that class, although I literally only just did it for knight right now but didn't get it. Not sure.